# software for privacy preserving data mining or cryptography

Tags: security, data-analysis, encryption

I want to implement K-means Clustering Data Mining using additive secret sharing.

This is a link to the research paper I am interested: [Vaidya's PPDM](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/clifton/DistDM/kdd02.pdf)

I want to know if there's any tool that contains cryptographic algorithms such as  Paillier's homomorphic encryption. Or any tool that I can test Privacy Preserving Data Mining with a cryptographic approach.